# How to add comments in Postman JSON body (for collection level pre-request script)

Tags: postman, postman-pre-request-script

I want to use comments within my JSON body for quick references like this:

```
{
    /**
    * some param info
    *   param: [
    *     1 = value so
    *     2 = value that
    *   ]
    */
    "param": [
        1
    ],
    /* some param2 info */
    "param2": "value",
    // pls use this
    "param3": [
        "values"
        //"home"
    ]
}
```

The comments should be filtered out before the request is getting sent to the server.

Answer (score 7):

Finally, since Postman v8.3.0 you can do this in your collections `pre-request` script:

```
// Strip JSON Comments
if (pm?.request?.body?.options?.raw?.language === 'json') {
    const rawData = pm.request.body.toString();
    const strippedData = rawData.replace(
        /\\"|"(?:\\"|[^"])*"|(\/\/.*|\/\*[\s\S]*?\*\/)/g,
        (m, g) => g ? "" : m
    );
    pm.request.body.update(JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(strippedData)));
}
```

This strips all comments from the json and sets the current body to the cleaned one, there are more examples for other body types (GraphQL, URL Encoded, Form Data) in the [original github post](https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/4808#issuecomment-826838064) this code is based from.

Comment: Also check the content type for your request. For me it became `text/plain`. To fix it I've added this bit after setting the request body: `pm.request.upsertHeader({ key: 'Content-Type', value: 'application/json' })`